# How to delete whitespace surrounding equal signs in a string?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, string, whitespace

I'm trying to determine a way to delete leading and trailing whitespace surrounding the equal sign from a string. The whitespace may (or may not) be present. There may be 0, 1 or more equal signs.

I've been trying to use `sed`, but its failing miserably to the point its not even worth showing what has not worked. I think I may be using the wrong tool for the job. I don't think `sed` or regular expressions can be used for this problem, but I could be wrong.

How do I delete whitespace between equal signs?

---

The actual problem is conceptually simple. I have a single string with zero or more `a=b` options. An option may be provided as `a=b`, `a = b` or maybe something like `a= b`. I need to normalize it to `a=b`.

There could be corner cases, like `CR` and `LF`, in a multiline string. I have not gotten to the point where breaking whitespace matters. If I can manage to get that far, then I'm inclined to call it malformed and reject a multiline string.

Comment: @don_crissti:  Post your answer as such if you tested it and it works.  At first glance it looks good.

Comment: Thanks Julie, that appears to work with the data I was testing. Don, how can I clear things up? What is unclear?

Comment: Don, would something like "the whitespace between the name/value pairs separated by an equal sign" be more clear? (I also tried to provide an examples: `a=b → a=b` (OK), `a = b → a=b` (remove whitespace) and `a= b → a=b` (remove whitespace)).

Comment: Julie or Don, would anyone like to answer? I tested both, and both work as expected.

Comment: @don_crissti:  you are asked to post your good answer.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Since neither don_crissti nor Julie Pelletier have converted the perfectly good comment into an answer, here's what Don came up with:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*/=/g'
```

... which uses regular expressions and a character class in `sed` to achieve the goal. The inner `[:blank:]` captures spaces or tabs; the outer `[]*` says to capture zero or more of those spaces/tabs; the equals sign stands for itself, then the same regular expression is repeated. The (optional) whitespace, equals-sign, and (optional) whitespace is all replaced with an equals-sign, and the `g` flag tells sed to repeat that search & replace on every match on the line.

Sample input:

```
$ cat input
a=b a = b a= b a =b
```

and output:

```
$ sed 's/[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*/=/g' input
a=b a=b a=b a=b
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with emacs:

```
$x replace-regexp
\s *=\s *
=
```

where `\s *=\s *` is the regexp that identifies any white space around an equals sign, and `=` is what it should be replace with.  Generally, `\sC` is interpreted as the character class `C`, in this case, white space (could be tabs also).  If you just want spaces, use `*` (that's a space before the *).

You seem to have a second question, `How do I delete whitespace between equal signs?`  In that case, you would want:

```
$x replace-regexp
=\s *=
==
```

I always have to re-lookup sed & awk.  If I can use it, I always go to emacs.  In emacs, you want to use `C-h i` to get to the info system, followed by `m emacs` to get to info on emacs, and then just search on `regexp` in that info page.

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned, but Perl:

```
s/\s*=\s*/=/g;
```